# Running JAVA Application online and connecting to website to update content

Tags: java, web-applications, server, hosted

i am running a website that basically shows an html table.

the data in this table is calculated by java application that runs on my computer.

the application needs to be started, and the data uploaded to the website.

no problem.

BUT: what i need to do , is install the application on some sort of server and make some sort of timer, to tell the app to run at a specific time, calculate the values for the table, and then upload the calculated data (table) to the website

is that possible?

in short || Java app now running on PC -> make run on server automatically -> calculate data -> upload data to website ||

thank u for your consideration and brain-juice invested

:)

Comment: This is basically what Java Enterprise Edition does.  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/overview/index.html  I recommend the Kathy Sierra book to get you started http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596516680.do

Comment: What you describe is a servlet. You should use something like Tomcat as the server.  Rather than using a static web page with a table, the servlet generates the HTML dynamically each time a page request is made so can use the most up to date values.

Comment: thanks guys, im looking into java EE  .. the servlet sounds good, but the values (table) take up to 2 hours to get calculated so i wouldnt prefer this version.. run once a day , preferably in the evening, and send the table to the website would be completely fine

Comment: This site is for very specific narrowly-focused questions aimed at  a certain programming problem. Broader discussions about general technologies in not appropriate here. Check out [Java Ranch](https://javaranch.com) for discussions.